# Running a function multiple times in R

Tags: r, function, csv, for-loop

I have 100 data set in *.csv format with the same name but different indexes: myarray1, myarray2,..., myarray100.
I have written a function to read these data sets and do some stuff but I don't want to run the function 100 times. This is the main part of function:

```
 Myfunc <- function(file){
 setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\mydaya")
 data.temp1 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\mydata\\myarray1.csv",header=FALSE)
 .......
 #core of function
 .....
 }
```

is it possible to write a for-loop somehow that runs the function itself 100 times and also change the index of "myarray..." in third command line inside the function at the same time: 
for example  myarray1 in

```
  data.temp <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\mydata\\myarray1.csv",header=FALSE)
```

becomes myarray2 in second run of the function  and so on up to 100 times.

Comment: yes but what do you want data.temp to look like after loading 100 files?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098368/how-do-i-concatenate-a-vector-of-strings-character-in-r

you can use a string concatenation in your for loop

Comment: @ Awokeknowing; Good question. Actually I correct it here. It should be data.temp+index and it changes each time when myarray changes. So at the end of the day I have 100 data.temp with the same name but different indices. data.temp1, data.temp2,...,data.temp100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't mean `read.csv(file, header=FALSE)` ?

Then you just can do

```
lapply(paste0("myarray", 1:100, ".csv"), Myfunc)
```

Comment: @ Neal Fultz; I used laply but I got this error message:                                 Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'myfunc' not found

Comment: R is case-sensitive; you need to match the capitalization between where you define your function and where you use it in `lapply()`.

Comment: yes I know. can you think of anything else that creates the error?

Comment: R isn't finding your function; run `ls()` and make sure it is there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to use variable names like that. You will be much better of storing the data in the list. I would suggest following methodology

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\mydata")
files <- dir(pattern = 'myarray.*\\.csv')

dataList <- lapply(files, FUN = Myfunc )
```

you can then refer to various dataframes by using dataList[[1]] , dataList[[2]] etc. It's much easer to work with list than variables list data.temp1, data.temp2 and so on.

Comment: @ geektrader; I used laply but I got this error message:                                 Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'myfunc' not found