# Using vector values for a graph title in R

Tags: r, concatenation, paste, substitution

I use two vectors in a function to obtain x values that I need to plot.
I want to add the values of the vectors in the title. I've been using this code that works well but, as the length of the vectors change, I need to modify the code and add, lets say, `p[2]` or `q[3]`.

```
p=3
q=c(1,2)
x= c(1:10)
plot(x,main=paste("Process X","\n Values p=",p," ; q=",q[1],",",q[2]))
```

I've realized that using just the name of the vector (as for p in the example) with a vector p of length=2, I get 2 titles superposed (one for each value of the vector).

I also used substitute() before paste function. In that case, I used just vector names without the brackets and get `c(1,2)` in the title which is ok for me but I don't know why `substitute()` don't allow nor "\n" to split lines  nor the bold format for the title.

Is there a way to get just the values of the vectors, independently of the length, and generate just one simple title?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I thought of one, but it's not too smart.

Firstly, create a vector of strings, which are paste of the value and some separation, like "," or "|":

```
for(i in seq(length(q)){
    q[i] <- paste(q[i], ",")
}
```

If you don't want any separation in the end, simply don't paste last element with any separation.

Secondly, paste all the strings, with the following code from the answer [Concatenate a vector of strings/character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098442/10181743):

```
str_q <- paste(q, collapse = "")
```

Finally, paste the string with your title.